# Changing the index blade in laravel issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-6

I have following in my laravel `web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    })->middleware('auth');

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

This would redirect my users back to login page if they are not logged in and logged in users would redirect to home page.

Now In my home controller index function I have following code,

```
public function index()
    {
        $get_customers = User::where('user_roles','=','customer')->get();
        $count_customers = $get_customers->count();

        $get_apps = Website::all();
        $count_apps = $get_apps->count();
        return view('home',compact('count_customers','count_apps'));
    }
```

When every time i'm trying to access my home page after logged in i'm getting an error saying

```
$count_apps is undefined
```

BUT,

When I used following routing in my `web.php` instead of previous routing, home page gives no error and works properly

```
Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('auth.login');
 })
```

But even though this made my login blade as the index page, every time when I try to access index as an already logged in user it keep redirecting me to the login blade not to he home blade....

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error:

```
$count_apps is undefined
```

becuase when you are calling this route:

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->middleware('auth');
```

And you are not **sending** the necessary data with the view which is in this case `$count_apps`

You should remove the faulty call to `home` **view** and and define it like this:

```
Route::get('/{name}', array(
     'as' => 'home', 
     'uses' => 'HomeController@index')
    )->where('name', '(home)?')->middleware('auth');
```

This will get url from `/` or `/home` and send it to `HomeController@index`.

Now if your website does not allow unauthenticated user to accses any route.

you should call the `auth` Middleware in the constructor of the controllers it would make your route file more readable

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
}
```

This will call the `auth` Middleware whenever a function in this controller is called